# Event for opened fires too soon in <paper-dialog>

Tags: polymer

I'm using <paper-dialog> to display an SVG image I'll construct programatically. I need to know the size of the rendered container before I begin. I am waiting for the opened property to change to true however that is apparently too soon as .clientWidth is 0 when it fires however later .clientWidth does provide the correct value.

```
<paper-dialog class="dialog" opened={{modalOpen}} modal>
     <svg width="100%", height="100%" />
</paper-dialog>
```

How can I wait for the SVG clientWidth and clientHeight to be computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer's `<paper-dialog>` implements [iron-resizable-behavior](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-resizable-behavior) so we can listen for the `iron-resize` event:

```
disconnectedCallback() {
    super.disconnectedCallback();
    this.removeEventListener('iron-resize', this.onIronResize);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes JS events are fired before the DOM has time to finish processing, which appears to be the case here.

To get around this (or at least to provide additional clues on what's happening), try putting your code (for the `clientWidth` property) within a `setTimeout()` function and give it a zero (0) millisecond timeout. This will simply move your code to the end of the JS execution stack, which should process only after the DOM has finished updating... and subsequently be when the DOM element's size and positioning properties are available.

Here's an example...

```
modalOpen() {
  setTimeout( () => {  
    /* Your code here... for example... */
    const paperDialog = document.getElementsByTagName("paper-dialog")[0];
    console.log("paperDialog width = ", paperDialog.clientWidth);  
  }, 0);  /* 0 milliseconds = Execute immediately after everything else processes. */
}
```

**WARNING:** Using `setTimeout()` is typically frowned upon since it doesn't fully adhere to asynchronous development and can produce unexpected results (such as firing too soon or not firing as soon as possible). While this approach is quick and can work fine some of the times, triggering and handling events are generally the best way to solve these timing issues.

Comment: A zero timeout didn't work.  A one second timeout does.

Comment: If a 1 millisecond timeout works, it likely means there's something else added to the executing stack earlier with a 0 timeout. This is another reason using built-in or customer events would be a better approach... you may have conflicts with other `setTimeout()`s.